# React Native, Passing Navigation to Stateless Flatlist component

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation, stateless

Currently I have:

```
return(
  <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.dataSource}
      renderItem={(data) => <EventCard eventinfo = {data.item} navigation= 
           {this.props.navigation}/>}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.eventname}
    />
```

and

```
const EventCard = ({eventinfo, navigation}) => {
return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}} onPress= {() 
     => navigation.navigate('CurrRes')}>
```

I dont understand why Navigation cant be evaluated in my Eventcard, and navigation doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated.

(yes withnavigation is imported in the first file and the project runs but crashes when one of the flatlist items is pressed)

The error i get is

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
```

Comment: have you solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I found to explain it better. 
You need to access props differently than just a normal function with deconstruction.

```
const Child = (props) => {
return (
  <div style={{backgroundColor: props.eyeColor}} />
 )
}
```

https://medium.com/@PhilipAndrews/react-how-to-access-props-in-a-functional-component-6bd4200b9e0b

Comment: this is react, im working in react native so there are no div tags, also I can do this here <Text>{eventinfo.eventname}</Text>, im just not sure how to get the navigation out so i can do navigation.navigate

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had to export the actual list with navigation so each of its nested stateless components could navigate. Sorry!